# Ni No Kuni Bounty Hunt 130

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

What is my best plan of attack here?
I have been running in circles healing Swaine and Esther while throwing Frostbite at the main enemy. I seem to run out of mana or get killed too soon for this to work though.

The only tip I found online was use Medals of Impunity. Any other help?